# Wrapping simple c++ example with ctypes; segmentation fault

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I extended the example provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145649/805357) by adding a private member variable, and printing it in the `bar()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo{
    private:
        double m;
    public:
        Foo() { m = 2.344; };
        void bar(){
            std::cout << "Hello, number is " << m << std::endl;
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

The `ctypes` wrapper was unchanged and is:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)



f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

When I run the python code (after having already compiled the C++ code earlier), I am getting a segmentation fault that I have narrowed down to the printing of `m` in `bar()`.

The seg fault does not happen

1. in the original code
2. if i remove printing of `m` but keep it as a variable
3. if i substitute `m` with any fixed number in `bar()`.

I am really puzzled why this should be happening. As this is an experiment to learn ctypes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not really with the `m` variable, but when the C++ code try to reference anything relative to `this`. I assume, for some reason, it is not correctly set. Could you add some debugging statements in your C++ code to track the address of the object created and the value of `this` when `Foo::bar()` is called?

Comment: try made bar in c++ class non-inline

Comment: I just tried the exact same code (g++ 4.4.5, Python 2.6.6), it worked like a charm.

Comment: If you're using 64-bit Python, you need to define `lib.Foo_new.restype = c_void_p`. Otherwise ctypes defaults to casting the return value to a 32-bit C `int`. You may also need to define `lib.Foo_bar.argtypes = [c_void_p]`; you should do that anyway.

Comment: @eryksun It worked! Thanks! The issue really was the 64bit python, and I wasn't aware of the casting. I should also note that following your comment I tested the code with 32bit python after having compiled the c code with -m32. That worked perfectly as well.

Comment: For future reference, could you post an answer with the corresponding changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 64-bit Python, you need to define the `restype` and `argtypes`. Otherwise ctypes defaults to casting the values to a 32-bit C `int`.

```
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL('./libfoo.so')

lib.Foo_new.argtypes = []
lib.Foo_new.restype = c_void_p

lib.Foo_bar.argtypes = [c_void_p]
lib.Foo_bar.restype = None
```

Here are source links for 2.7.5, Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c:

- [`ConvParam` (Lines 645-663)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l559)
- [`GetResult` (Lines 914-915)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l899)

For 64-bit Windows a C `long` is 32-bit, but it's 64-bit on most other 64-bit platforms. By forcing `int` the result is at least consistent.