# Cant set variable inside wrapped c++ (C api to python) class. Ok from "inside", but not when imported

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, ctypes

I've created python file which wrapps a C++ file (C-api).

When the pythonfile (test.py), which imports the "so"-file, is executed the methods is executed as expected. Test.py has a main() where the object is created and method is called.
But! When I import the pythonfile(together with so-file) I am not able to read/write variables inside the C++ file. When trying to do so the application crashes.

The C++ file, which is wrapped with C-api / ctypes/python

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    private:
        int temp;
    public:
    void tst(){
        std::cout << "TST1 " << std::endl;
        this->temp = 5;                   <<<<< CRASHES HERE (1)
        std::cout << "TST2 " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "TST tempvalue: " << temp << std::endl;

    }
    void bar(){
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello, TEST:" << this->temp << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(){
        std::cout << "FOO INIT" << std::endl;
        this->temp = 34;
        std::cout << "FOO INIT END" << std::endl;
    }
};


extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){
        foo->bar();
    }
    void Foo_tst(Foo* foo){
        std::cout << ".CPP - TST - start" << std::endl;
        foo->tst();
        std::cout << ".CPP - TST - END" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

test.py, this file connects the C++ code to python code.

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./app/modules/testmod/libfoo.so')
#lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "test.py - init"
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        print "test.py - bar"
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)
        print "test.py - bar - ending"

    def tst(self):
        print "test.py - tst"
        lib.Foo_tst(self.obj)
        print "test.py - tst - ending"
```

The python application:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response, send_file
#import time
#import numpy as np
#import ctypes as C
#import cv2
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'app/modules/')
from testmod import test            #<<<- testmod folder is insides app/modules/


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index/')
def index():
    tc = test.Foo()
    tc.tst()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Okay. So.
If I at the bottom of "test.py" writes the following code:

```
tc = Foo()
tc.tst()
ts.bar()
```

With (1), (2) uncommented the code executes correctly, and outputs everything.
But when I import test.py into another project program stops. For every new method call The variable "temp" in .cpp file is null. if I try to print it out to the console the software crash.

If I remove every variable setting/reading (only output text to terminal, std::cout<<...) the methods executes as it should.

I found that when setting the variable temp inside the Foo-constructor (cpp file) the variable is set. but when calling "tst()" variable temp can't be edited or read.

I really hope that someone can find what's wrong with the code.

Thanks!

Comment: In test.py define `lib.Foo_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p;` `lib.Foo_bar.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,);` `lib.Foo_tst.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)`.

Comment: Okay, What is that? I added it. And now it seems to work. I would appreciate if you could create an answer, so that I can mark your answer as the correct one :D, if you have the time, please add an explanation of what that is?!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242397), and read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) on defining function prototypes.